# Equal space between elements INSIDE a column bootstrap 5

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

So imagine a bootstrap column full of elements (divs, paragraphs, links.. ) how do I space those elements equally inside that column, like space-between alignment or space-around. I don't want margins or padding. I want *elements* to **automatically equally space around the free space vertically inside a column**.

In the documentation for flex everything seems to be focused on rows and what little there is for columns it's aligning elements inside a column horizontally.

Any ideas how I can get the desired effect?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution could be adding `flex` positioning to your column as well. So you can add those additional classes that are provided by bootstrap.

```html
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col d-flex flex-column justify-content-between">
        <!-- Here comes your content -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Since you want to evenly space the element is the y axis, you need to add `flex-column`. Also remember you can nest any number of `flex` boxes inside another.

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly. I feel like this would be a great example for the docs.